# Can't get the exact result I was hoping for

Tags: java

```
class A{
   public int x;
    A(int x){
      this.x=x;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public  int y;

    B(int x,int y){
        super(x);
        this.y=y;
    }

    int s=x+y;

    public void sum(){
        System.out.println("Sum is :"+s);
    }
}

public class Inheritance_2 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         B obj =new B(20,30);
         obj.sum();
     }
}
```

In this code, i wanna know why my sum is not 50 when I use `s=x+y` and print s?

But when I print `(x+y)` directly it gives the accurate result as  50.

Comment: Your field int `s=x+y;` gets initialized before `this.y=y;` is executed. And it only gets initialized once at that specific time when `x` is `20` and `y` is still `0`

Answer (score 0):

you should add the sum inside the method :D

```
public void sum(){
    int s=x+y;
    System.out.println("Sum is :"+s);
}
```

Comment: Why is that actually ??

Comment: what do you get now? 0? this is because when you create the instance x & y are by default 0. Other option is to edit the constructor and add at the end this.s = x + y;